# How to speed up a query using function and indexing on Informix

Tags: sql, function, indexing, informix

Under Informix Dbms I need to speed up this query:

```
set isolation to dirty read;
SELECT NVL(hr_dati1, '---'), NVL(cm_t_stoc, -1) as type,
LPAD(cm_mod,3, 0)||LPAD(cm_col,3, 0) as coord,
NVL(cm_segmento, 0) as seg, NVL(cm_lres, 0) 
FROM informix.artind, informix.coordman
LEFT OUTER JOIN informix.hmdescr ON cm_t_stoc = hr_key_soc AND 
hr_key_pref = 'MGZ' AND hr_key_suff = 'STOCC'
WHERE cm_magaz = '5' AND ad_code = '2065498' AND 
((cm_code = '2065498') OR
((cm_code = ad_coor_r) AND ( SUBSTR(NVL(ad_coor_r, ' '), 1, 2) = 'MU' )
AND
( SUBSTR(NVL(cm_code, ' '), 1, 2) = 'MU' ) ))
ORDER BY type, seg, coord;
```

The above query was faster when I used as
filter only

```
(cm_code = '2065498')
```

instead of

```
((cm_code = '2065498') OR
((cm_code = ad_coor_r) AND ( SUBSTR(NVL(ad_coor_r, ' '), 1, 2) = 'MU')      
AND
( SUBSTR(NVL(cm_code, ' '), 1, 2) = 'MU' ) ))
```

but now a I need to add this new condition.

In the search for an optimization, and I believe that the slowness is due to the substr I have created this function:

```
create function informix.substr2_ad_coor_r(coor_r char(8))
  returning char(8) with (NOT VARIANT);
  return substr(coor_r, 1, 2);
end function;
```

and the these indices:

```
create index informix.artind_idx_sub_coor_r on informix.artind
 ( informix.substr2_ad_coor_r(ad_coor_r));

create index informix.coordman_idx_sub_codifa on informix.coordman
 ( informix.substr2_ad_coor_r(cm_codifa));
```

but I have not improved the speed enough, also the strange thing is that the query seems faster if I use, in the filter condition, substr eg.`(SUBSTR(NVL(ad_coor_r, ' '), 1, 2) = 'MU')`  instead of substr2_ad_coor_r eg. `substr2_ad_coor_r(ad_coor_r) = 'MU'`

Comment: Which version of Informix are you using? What is the structure of the tables involved? Which indexes exist? Can you publish the output of the `EXPLAIN` for both queries ?

Comment: Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  This is harder in SQL than some other tags; the MCVE includes outline schemas for the tables (the referenced columns and primary key identification in particular), and simple sample data, the desired output from the sample data, and (if applicable) that actual output and what's different about it.

Answer (score 0):

I speeded up the query by splitting it into 2 using the union:

```
set isolation to dirty read;
SELECT NVL(hr_dati1, '---'), NVL(cm_t_stoc, -1) as type,
LPAD(cm_mod,3, 0)||LPAD(cm_col,3, 0) as coord,
NVL(cm_segmento, 0) as seg, NVL(cm_lres, 0)
FROM informix.artind, informix.coordman
LEFT OUTER JOIN informix.hmdescr ON cm_t_stoc = hr_key_soc AND
hr_key_pref = 'MGZ' AND hr_key_suff = 'STOCC'
WHERE cm_magaz = '5' AND ad_code = '2065498' AND
(cm_code = '2065498')
UNION
SELECT NVL(hr_dati1, '---'), NVL(cm_t_stoc, -1) as type,
LPAD(cm_mod,3, 0)||LPAD(cm_col,3, 0) as coord,
NVL(cm_segmento, 0) as seg, NVL(cm_lres, 0)
FROM informix.artind, informix.coordman
LEFT OUTER JOIN informix.hmdescr ON cm_t_stoc = hr_key_soc AND
hr_key_pref = 'MGZ' AND hr_key_suff = 'STOCC'
WHERE cm_magaz = '5' AND ad_code = '2065498' AND
((cm_code = ad_coor_r) AND ( SUBSTR(NVL(ad_coor_r, ' '), 1, 2) = 'MU' )
AND
( SUBSTR(NVL(cm_code, ' '), 1, 2) = 'MU' ) )
ORDER BY 1, 3, 2;
```